# Why does R studio not read R codes?

Tags: rstudio, h2o, iml

Several of the codes I wrote last month have become extremely large (2MB - 11MB) and are no longer readable. Does anybody know what happened?

All of the codes used the iml package and possibly h2o

This is what left of them:
[image]

Comment: What happens if you open them in something like notepad?

Comment: Just Gibberish, same with Atom.

Comment: I'm afraid the file got corrupted somehow.